# Expose an event from C# plugin and access in js for cordova

Tags: c#, javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I have developed a plugin in cordova for windows phone 8. It is like a upload functionality where I keep uploading data in background and return success once done.
Here I want to return percentage of file uploaded in between, I am planning to expose it through `progressevent`.

I am using `PhoneGap 2.3` where it is not already provided in `FileTransfer` class.

How to create and fire an event so that I can access it in javascript??

I tried using command dispatcher but it calls success function and not the function which has subscribed to onProgress event.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the latest Cordova FileTransfer code, you'll want to do something similar. https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/blob/master/www/FileTransfer.js

In you C# code, hold a reference to the callback and continuously call the callback with progress data. Remember to set KeepCallBack to true.

```
PluginResult result = new PluginResult(progressData);
result.KeepCallback = true;
DispatchCommandResult(result);
```

In JavaScript the success handler will get the progress data. `FileTransfer#upload` handles this by create a new success callback that either calls `onprogress` or the `successCallback`, depending on the data received. https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/blob/651460fb6b41035c96bcc31a38621ec8100648f1/www/FileTransfer.js#L133